# Differences between gamma correction and exposure in image processing

Tags: image-processing

Anyone know what is the difference between gamma and exposure? And what is the difference between gamma correction and exposure adjustment in image processing?

Comment: This is an informal [Adobe white paper](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/linear_gamma.pdf) on (digital) exposure and gamma correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gamma correction is a non-linear global function that compresses certain ranges in your image. It is mainly used in order to be more efficient from human vision point of view, in fixed point format. It is absent in raw files, but exists in JPEG. Each pixel undergoes the following transformation:

```
 y = x^p
```

Exposure is a physical phenomenon in your camera. Exposure adjustment on the other hand is linear global function. It is used mainly in order to compensate for lack or excess of exposure in the camera:

```
 y = a*x
```

Comment: erm..thank you but can you explain in more simple way, plz? thx. What is x,p and a?

Comment: x is the the exposure value, the amount of light hitting the sensor, p is the gamma correction factor, and a is the exposure correction multiplier. It shows that gamma correction is non-linear (does not effect all exposure values equally) and exposure is linear (multiplies all exposure values equally)

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't have an image processing background i would start with a basics

1) Every digital image has a dynamic range of gray levels.Now gray levels are nothing but values which ultimately corresponds to a color. Say Mono-chrome image(Black and white image) has only 2 gray levels i.e. 0 and 1 where 0 means black and 1 means white color. Here the dynamic range is [0-1]. In these images each pixel is stored as a single bit.

Similarly there is Gray-scale images have shades of gray in them. Here each pixel is stored as 8-bit so dynamic range is [0-255]. How? just apply the formula (2^n -1) where n is number of bits. i.e. (2^8 - 1) i.e. 256-1 = 255.

Similarly there are color-images which are 24-bit images.In general the dynamic range of gray levels in image is given by [0 - L-1] where L is number of gray levels.

2) Now once you have understood what is dynamic range lets understand Gamma correction.
Gamma correction is nothing but a function that compress the dynamic range of images so that we can view the image more nicely or properly. But why do we need to compress dynamic range? 
 **A best day to day example is during day time when we cannot see the stars, the reason is because the intensity of sun is so large as compared to the intensity of stars that we cannot see the stars in day time.**
Similarly when dynamic range is high in an image then that of the display device we cannot see the image properly. Therefore we can use gamma correction to compress the dynamic range of image
3) Gamma correction can be written as  **g(x,y) = c * f(x,y) ^ #**  where # is symbol of gamma (since i don't know how to write gamma symbol here, i have used #) and f(x,y) is original image with high dynamic range, g(x,y) is modified image. C is a positive constant.
4) Exposure as said earlier in an answer its phenomena in camera. I don't know much about it as it is not covered in the syllabus of image processing which i am currently studying.

Comment: wow...this is clear and good explanation! thx a lot @R122. Does gamma correction application to all type of images such as jpeg?

Comment: @ATZ---- I am just a beginner in image processing and as far as i know yes gamma correction is applicable to all type of images

Comment: +1 - Good answer. However, I think that there is a small thing missing in it - the compression is needed because humans have logarithmic perception of light intensity.

Answer (score 2):

Exposure is an indication of the total quantity of light that reaches the CCD of your camera (or the silver ions on film).  It can be expressed as the number of photons that hit your image-recording elements.

Films and CCD are calibrated to expect a certain quantity of light (certain number of photons) in order to be able to create an "average" image.
The higher the "expected" quantity of light, the lower the ISO number of your film (or camera setting) => in order to obtain a normal image, a film (or camera setting) of 100 ISO needs more light than a film of 3200 ISO, hence the use of 3200 ISO films for night photography.

next step: the camera thing.  When you want to make a picture (= have photons hit your CCD or film), you need to open the diaphragm of your camera.  Depending on how much you open your diaphragm, the nature of your image will change (speaking from an artistic point of view here). If your diaphragm is wide open, most of the image which is not perfectly in focus will be blurred (e.g. as used in portrait photography).  Conversely, if your diaphragm is only a little bit open during exposure, most of your image will be very sharp.  This is used very often for landscape photography.

As your film (or CCD) expect a certain quantity of light with a given ISO value, it is obvious that a smaller diaphragm opening requires longer exposure times whereas a wide open diaphraghm requires a very short time.

Good books about this subject are the series "The Camera", "The Negative" and "The Print" by Ansel Adams.

Conclusion: exposure and gamma correction are different things.
- Exposure is a part of the parameters you need to control while creating your initial image through the use of a camera.
- Gamma correction is related to subsequent manipulation of your image file.  I'm not sure if the notion of "gamma correction" is being used in the context of film.

Answer (score -6):

Basically:

Gamma is a monitor thing.

Exposure is a camera thing.

Comment: Basically this answer is useless.